# Regex matching an Ant-path

Tags: python, regex, ant

I have a simple task - I am given a path and an Ant-pattern in two strings and I want to know if the path fits into the pattern. That is it.

e.g. The pattern could be

```
foo/*/bar/**.ext
```

and then different paths would be tested for a simple `true / false` match.

Right now I am using the `fnmatch` package, but that does not work 100% correctly. It basically merges `*` into `**` and will match too many files.

I am looking for a solution in Python or general way to generate the regular expressions that will allow me to do the matches.

Comment: Be aware that "Unix filename pattern matching" and "regular expressions" are two different things. Ant-style patterns such as `**/CVS/*` are more on the "Unix filename pattern matching" side of concepts than on the "regular expression" side. Perhaps removing "regex" from your searches will help you find a useful library?

Comment: @MartinMelka: no luck with my path translation regex?

Comment: Yeah I've been playing around with a similar one, but your solution seems to match correctly whatever I can think of. I will do some more tests :)

Comment: @MartinMelka: sorry for bother you again, if the proposed solutions works please accept it or it needs to be refined you may provide one or more failing paths. I'll write some code to stress the proposed solution against them. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't swear this is a bulletproof solution in every case but you can try to filter every sensible char in the path with this:

- dot `.` with a backslash dot `\.`
- ant star `*` with an equivalent `[^\/]+`
- ant double star `**` with regex-style `.*`
- slash `/` escaped with `\/` (this works only on unix-like path)
- question mark `?` with word single char `\w` (this matches only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` can be more strict than the OS' rule regarding the chars allowed in a filename)

This is the relevant code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

star = r"[^\/]+"
doubleStar = r".*"
slash = r"\/"
questionMark = r"\w"
dot = r"\."

antPath = "foo/*/bar/**.ex?"
expectedPath = r"foo\/[^\/]+\/bar\/.*\.ex\w"

# Apply transformation
output = antPath.replace(r"/", slash).replace(r".", dot)
output = re.sub(r"(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)", star, output)
output = output.replace(r"**", doubleStar)
output = output.replace(r"?", questionMark)

if (output == expectedPath):
    print "Success!"
else:
    print "Failure..."
print "filteredPath: ", output
print "expectedPath: ", expectedPath
```

Try online [here](http://ideone.com/TrHBWj)